# How to interpret strongly/weakly infinite dimensional spaces and what are some examples?

Tags: general-topology, definition, examples-counterexamples, geometric-interpretation

I have a question regarding strongly infinite dimensional spaces. Loosely speaking, $X$ is called **strongly infinite dimensional** if any pair of closed disjoint sets can be separated by a subset $L_i$ and all such subsets have nonempty intersection. If $X$ isn´t strongly infinite dimensional, it is called **weakly infinite dimensional**.

My questions:

1. What does this property intuitively telling us about the space? And why is it called like this, what does it have to do with dimension? It seems to me most examples I can think of, like $\mathbb{R}$ or $l^2$, are strongly infinite dimensional.
2. Could you provide examples for strongly dimensional and weakly infinite dimentional spaces?

Thank you for your advice.

For the better context, the definition of a strongly infinite dimensional space is included below.**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that $\Bbb R$ is strongly infinite dimensional? Can you give me two pairs $(A_i,B_i)$ forming an essential family?

Comment: For example: $A_1 = [0,1], B_1 = [2,3], L_1 = [3/2,7/4]$ and $A_2 = [-1,0], B_2 = [3,4], L_2 = [1/2,1]$. Then intersection of $L_1, L_2$ is nonempty and without them, the space can still be divided into the part containing $A_i$ and part containing $B_i$.

Comment: Okay, but for $\mathbb{R}$ to be strongly infinite dimensional, you'd have to find an infinite essential family.  What did you have in mind for that?

Comment: The way I read the definition is that however you pick the $L_i$ their intersection must be nonempty, not that you can pick a particular family of $L_i$s with nonempty intersections

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, okay, that´s what I was missing.